# Ajax datatable bSortable

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am using ajax dataTable for view a list of books and I am using cakePHP. This is my script to call ajax datatable:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    oTable = $('#base_discount').dataTable({
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bServerSide": true,
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "aoColumns"   : [{"sClass": "center"}, null, null,{"sClass": "center"} ,{"sClass": "center"},{"sClass": "center"},{"sClass": "center"}, {"bSortable": true,"sClass": "center"}, **{"bSortable": false,"sClass": "center"}**],
        "sAjaxSource": "<?php echo BASE_PATH?>xxx/xxx.ctp"
    });
});
```

In the last of `aColumns` I set `bSortable` as `false` and also in the last column I set the checkbox to check and uncheck all. This is a script for check and uncheck:

```
function toggle(source) {
    checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('foo');
    for(var i in checkboxes)
        checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
}
```

This checkbox is working fine. But in datatable the grid in the last column shows like this: [image]

Please help me...

Thank You

Comment: Relevant HTML Code means, i think there is problem in ajax datatable, when i remove bSortable: false means, its working fine. But i need last column in datatable should not be sortable.